# Returning Json instead of XML with Umbraco Base

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, response, umbraco

I have a .NET method that adds a new member to my DB. It does this through an AJAX request. I have this working correctly, however I am having problems returning the correct response message so I can print the correct messages to the user.

My method at the moment looks like this:

```
    public static string MemberRegister(int process)
    {

        //here we find form values posted to the current page
        HttpRequest post = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        //get values from ajax URL
        var name = post["name"];
        var email = post["email"];
        var username = post["username"];
        var password = post["password"];

        //check if email exists
        if (Member.GetMemberFromEmail(email) == null)
        {

            MemberType userMemberType = new MemberType(1111); //id of membertype 'demo'
            Member newMember = Member.MakeNew(name, userMemberType, new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));

            newMember.AddGroup(MemberGroup.GetByName("Active").Id);
            newMember.Email = email;
            newMember.Password = password;
            newMember.LoginName = username;

            newMember.Save();

            return "success";
        }
        else
        {
            return "emailError";
        }        

    }
```

My Ajax code looks like:

```
        // submit
    $registerForm.submit(function() {

            $loader.show();

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/processform.aspx",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize()

            }).complete(function( response ) {

            alert(response.responseText);

                if( response.responseText === "success" ) {
                    $registerSuccess.fadeIn(); 
                } elseif( response.responseText === "emailError" ) {
                    $registerEmailError.fadeIn(); 
                } else {
                    $registerError.slideDown();                        
                }

                $loader.hide();

            });



            return false;

    });
```

For example if the member all ready exists it returns the reponse:

```
<value>emailError</value>
```

I just want it to return emailError not the value tags as well. How do I do this?

Fiddler (Raw):

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 20:59:54 GMT
 Content-Length: 25

 <value>emailError</value>


    POST http://domain.com/base/Forms/MemberRegister/process.aspx HTTP/1.1
    Host: domain.com
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 125
    Origin: http://domain.com
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Referer: http://domain/register.aspx
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ys4mmhsn2mpqcpja1iyjg04m; UMB_UPDCHK=1; __utma=256732567.15732944.1331581910.1332617890.1332627641.11; __utmc=256732567; __utmz=256732567.1331581910.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); UMB_UCONTEXT=12621b40-16fe-4422-a027-cf4fa68fe03d; __utma=176230262.1311679778.1332368941.1332694687.1332708163.12; __utmb=176230262.3.10.1332708163; __utmc=176230262; __utmz=176230262.1332368941.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

    __VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUENTM4MWRkEytUM47m6NUA6dpfOudOh9t51j6okfG%2BQhu4Em%2B26KU%3D&name=ppp&email=ppp&username=ppp&username=ppp
```

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 9):

Here's a good example of how to return a JSON object with Umbraco Base:

```
/* Be sure to add References to:
 * 
 * umbraco.dll
 * System.Web.dll
 * System.Web.Extensions.dll
 */

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

using umbraco.presentation.umbracobase;

namespace CoB.Umb.Base.Example
{
    [RestExtension("Example")]
    public class Example
    {
        [RestExtensionMethod(returnXml = false, allowAll = true)]
        public static void Get()
        {
            string json = "";

            var person = new
            {
                firstName = "John",
                lastName = "Doe"
            };

            json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(person);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
        }
    }
}
```

And the javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/base/Example/Get', function (data) {
    alert("Hey, " + data.firstName + " " + data.lastName);
});
```

Comment: in my 4.7.2 install the attribute doesn't work in the class file, I have to add it to the restExtensions config file to make it work

Comment: The RestExtension attributes have been around since [Umbraco 4.6](http://snipplr.com/view/45818/umbraco-juno-restextension-and-restextensionmethod-attribute/). I use them on 4.7.2 just fine. They even work in the [app_code folder](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/33286-Base-RestExtension-without-compiled-DLL-possible). Maybe you're missing a [dependency](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/16512-base-adding-class-file-to-App_Code-not-working-What-gives) on the server?

Comment: This is a really clean and nice example - and worked perfectly for me using 4.7.2.  Thanks a ton for sharing your great solution.

Comment: You can also just return the json instead of doing any response.write (though the content-type is likely wrong: I'm getting "text/html").

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://encosia.com/jquery-for-the-asp-net-developer/) is amazing for helping with ASP.NET jQuery Ajax calls, [this post](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) in particular

Adrian Iftode is correct with his answer, but you don't need to set a response format on the server. If you ask for JSON the server will automatically encode to that. This is handy if you have multiple services calling the webservices and you need to encode differently for them.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

I also found [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service) helpful when I started to do this. It gives some code that moves all the $.ajax calls into one place.

```
// *** Service Calling Proxy Class
function serviceProxy(serviceUrl){
var _I = this;    this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;     
// *** Call a wrapped object
    this.invoke = function(method,data,callback,error,bare)
    {
        // *** Convert input data into JSON - REQUIRES Json2.js
        var json = JSON2.stringify(data);
        // *** The service endpoint URL
        var url = _I.serviceUrl + method;
         $.ajax( {
                     url: url,
                    data: json,
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    timeout: 10000,
                    dataType: "text",  // not "json" we'll parse
                    success:
                     function(res)
                     {
                         if (!callback) return;
                         // *** Use json library so we can fix up MS AJAX dates 
                         var result = JSON2.parse(res);
                         // *** Bare message IS result
                        if (bare)
                        { callback(result); return; }
                         // *** Wrapped message contains top level object node
                        // *** strip it off
                        for(var property in result)
                        {
                            callback( result[property] );
                            break;
                        }
                    },
                    error:  function(xhr) {
                        if (!error) return;
                        if (xhr.responseText)
                        {
                            var err = JSON2.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            if (err)
                                error(err);
                             else
                                error( { Message: "Unknown server error." })
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                });
       }} 
    // *** Create a static instance
    var Proxy = new serviceProxy("JsonStockService.svc/");
    // *** Call the webservice
    Proxy.invoke("GetStockQuote",{ symbol: symbol },function(result){...}, onPageError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to decorate the method to return Json

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static string MemberRegister(int process)


complete(function( response ) {
   if (response.d == "success") {
     //
    }
}
```

edit

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/processform.aspx",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $(this).serialize()

            })..
```

Comment: Still returning the value tags. Any other suggestions?

What is the difference using reponse.d?

Comment: when a JSON is returned it looks like {"d": "success"} ( Fiddler will help you to see the exact response of the request)

Comment: Ok I can see with fiddler that the response header looks like, Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8, therefore its still returning XML.

Comment: can you post here the response?

Comment: I have made those edits all ready to the jQuery. The full response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 18:18:00 GMT
Content-Length: 25

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. I now have it returning Json which the question was for.

Comment: Clearly you didn't fix the issue, but you are on right path with this approach and the second question you asked was far from the right path. Edit this one and post the entire response you see with Fiddler, not only the headers. Also you can remove irrelevant code (honestly here it matters only the return type and can be one of those two strings) and show the attributes over the method (WebMethod etc).

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm fairly new to .NET so learning as I go along. I have added extra fiddler information above.

Answer (score -2):

Finally figured it out!

I needed to add "returnXml = false" to one of my class calls.

Comment: As above, can you provide info? I'm curious.

Comment: In general, when you find a solution to a particular problem, it is nice to provide a full answer as well. The whole concept is to share information, not only try to get it from others.

Comment: If anyone needs this, the `returnXml = False` goes in the constructor for the RestExtensionMethod attribute. See Douglas Ludlow's answer above for an example.