# Publish one product to multiple sites

Tags: dotnetnuke, umbraco

Is there a way to have one product definition and have it publish to multiple sites?  I am looking for this ability specifically in DNN or Umbraco, either with free or paid extensions.  I did install both the platforms and played with the free extensions and looked for any extension offering such functionality but did not find one.  Any links or pointers are highly appreciated!

I had looked up for this info in many places before reaching over to the expert pool here, hoping to get some hints;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In umbraco there is the built in /base extension (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-base) which enables you to access product data that is maintained in Umbraco from other websites.  Base is REST-ish so the implementation is well documented - you can access the data as XML or JSON ([Returning Json instead of XML with Umbraco Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861285/returning-json-instead-of-xml-with-umbraco-base)).

Also as the implementation is REST-ish the other websites that consume the content maintained in the core site could be written in anything that can consume a REST feed eg html & javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear to me what setup you're after, but if you're looking to set up a traditional Authoring/Delivery configuration - one of the few paid offerings Umbraco has is called [Courier](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx). It's a very reasonably priced (~$135USD,/99EUR) deployment manager that handles syncing content between two sites, i.e., Authoring and a Delivery server. 
It's a very smart tool that manages content, configuration, and dependencies. It's neat and also supports a great open-source project!

If you're looking to setup something more like a centralized product database that is used by many sites - amelvin is on good pointer with BASE. They have a nice api where you may also set up your own webservice (beyond their own webservice functaionality!).
If you need this centralized product data to notify the other sites to update their caches - i encourage you to look into the 'distributedCall' functionality. 
There's a bit of documentation on [distributed calls in this load-balancing tutorial](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/installation/load-balancing#UmbracoConfiguration) that may help understand the concept a bit better.

...Hope this helps get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You got it right in the 2nd paragraph - I am after setting up single product definition feeding in to multiple stores.  That, with inventory management so that if a product is sold from any of the stores the inventory of the product is updated automatically in all stores without having to wait for the content synchronization/syndication back/forth.  I shall study the Base.  Also, thanks for the link to load-balancing tutorial.